# cassandra dependencies issue: not found CassandraJavaUtil

Tags: apache-spark

I try to launch a  little app that only read a table from a cassandra database.

Launched app with spark-submmit:

> - /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class com.baitic.mcava.pruebacassandra.PruebaCassandraBBDD  --master spark://192.168.1.105:7077 --executor-memory 1G /home/miren/NetBeansProjects/PruebaCassandra/target/original-PruebaCassandra-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar   --deploy-mode  cluster

output before i launched it, only show the break point of output, the rest of it work well:

> 16/02/25 11:18:34 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/CassandraJavaUtil
>       at com.baitic.mcava.pruebacassandra.PruebaCassandraBBDD.main(PruebaCassandraBBDD.java:71)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 10 more

I create a maven java app, then i put the pom.xml with the necessary dependencies:

> org.apache.spark
>               spark-core_2.10
>               1.6.0

```
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

imports :

- import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
- import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
- import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
- import  org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
- import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
- importorg.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
- import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;

....

code main:

> JavaRDD cassandraRowsRDD =
>   javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("ks", "sensor_readings")
>               .map(new Function(){
>                   @Override
>                   public String call(CassandraRow cassandraRow) throws Exception{
>                       return cassandraRow.toString();
>                   }
>               });
>
> ```
> System.out.println("Data as CassandraRows \n"+ StringUtils.join(cassandraRowsRDD.toArray(),"\n"));
> ```

Comment: I solve the problem...i compile de cassandra jar and not add through maven. I use sbt and i get the jar file and add the path in spark-default.sh. But the app still not work now i have a problem with serializable when i call the metod collet()

Comment: I solve all the problem the app works perfect.....

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the following in your import statements:

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*;
```

If you are running this code with any custom classes the jar file path will need to be added to the spark-defaults.conf file with the parameter:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath     /whateverpath/to/file/
```

Comment: yes i have all the imports, and i do not use any custom class. I do not understant why i have this error.

Comment: Change this line:`import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions;` to `import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.*;`

Comment: i did it but i have the same error. I am very confused with it

Answer (score 0):

Try using --jars option in spark submit command. download cassandra jar and specify name of the cassandra jar in --jars option or specify it as extraClassPath in spark env file.

Comment: i add in spark-default.sh two options spark spark.driver.extraClassPath PATHOFTHECASSANDRAJAVAJAR and spark.executor.extraClassPath PATHOFTHECASSANDRAJAVAJAR  but i have the same error. I also add in the app code the same path in setJars(). I cant find in env.sh the variable extra_pathclass

Comment: Can you please try using option --jars "path to cassandra jar" in spark-submit command and let me know if it works. Try something like this  spark-submit --master yarn-client --executor-memory 4g --num-executors 4 --driver-memory 5g --jars /home/rgulati/spark_jars/commons-csv-1.2.jar,/home/rgulati/spark_jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.0.jar

Comment: I think that it is better to add the path of the jars in de spark Context...i did it and work perfect. Also you can put this path in the spark-default.sh (spark.driver.extraclassPath spark.executor.extraClassPath). In my deploy i write the jar path in the spark-default.sh and add the path of my jar in the spark conf in the java code and it is work perfect. Sorry for my English....

Comment: Yes Miren you can do this either way. I suggested above method because you mentioned earlier that after adding path in spark-default.sh you still getting same error. But i am glad finally it worked.